# xdebug not showing up in php info

Tags: php, mamp, xdebug, osx-elcapitan, bitnami

php.ini

```
zend_extension="/Applications/mampstack-5.6.18-0/php/lib/php/extensions/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/tmp
```

I followed all the steps in the https://xdebug.org/wizard.php

```
Xdebug installed: no
Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler
Windows: no
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 5.6.18
Zend API nr: 220131226
PHP API nr: 20131226
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: no
Configuration File Path: /bitnami/mampstack-osx-x64/output/php/lib
Configuration File: /Applications/mampstack-5.6.18-0/php/etc/php.ini
Extensions directory: /Applications/mampstack-5.6.18-0/php/lib/php/extensions



Download xdebug-2.4.0rc4.tgz
Unpack the downloaded file with tar -xvzf xdebug-2.4.0rc4.tgz
Run: cd xdebug-2.4.0rc4
Run: phpize (See the FAQ if you don't have phpize.

As part of its output it should show:

Configuring for:
...
Zend Module Api No:      20131226
Zend Extension Api No:   220131226
If it does not, you are using the wrong phpize. Please follow this FAQ entry and skip the next step.

Run: ./configure
Run: make
Run: cp modules/xdebug.so /Applications/mampstack-5.6.18-0/php/lib/php/extensions
Edit /Applications/mampstack-5.6.18-0/php/etc/php.ini and add the line
zend_extension = /Applications/mampstack-5.6.18-0/php/lib/php/extensions/xdebug.so
Restart the webserver
```

php -v

> PHP 5.5.30 (cli) (built: Oct 23 2015 17:21:45) Copyright (c) 1997-2015
>   The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend
>   Technologies

But still not showing up

Comment: @fico7489 no changes after restart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitnami Developer here,

MAMP 5.6.18 includes Xdebug. However, it has a minor issue that we are working on fixing for the next revision.

Anyway, you can follow the steps below:

```
brew install autoconf automake
/Applications/mampstack-5.6.18-0/use_mampstack
curl > 'xdebug-2.4.0RC4.tgz' https://pecl.php.net/get/xdebug-2.4.0RC4.tgz
tar -zxf xdebug-2.4.0RC4.tgz
cd xdebug-2.4.0RC4/
export PHP_AUTOCONF=/usr/local/bin/autoconf
export PHP_PREFIX=/Applications/mampstack-5.6.18-0/php
phpize
./configure --enable-xdebug
make
sudo make install
```

Then, you only need to add the code below in */Applications/mampstack-5.6.18-0/php/etc/php.ini*:

```
;[XDebug]
;; Only Zend OR (!) XDebug
zend_extension="/Applications/mampstack-5.6.18-0/php/lib/php/extensions/xdebug.so"
;xdebug.remote_enable=true
;xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
;xdebug.remote_port=9000
;xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
;xdebug.profiler_enable=1
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/tmp
```

Restart the services:

```
/Applications/mampstack-5.6.18-0/ctlscript.sh restart
```

You can check it executing `php -m | grep xdebug`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I will try, muchos gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Same issue over here. I've been trying hundreds of options and downloading older version of php fixed my problem, so if you won't find any better fix so maybe this will also help you. Good luck.